# VBA Userform not outputting runtime errors

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I have a userform that opens several files and processes them. But I just realized the program doesn't stop or output any runtime errors when there is one. For example,

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as worksheet

set ws = wb.sheets("Random")
```

Even if there's no sheet in the workbook named "Random", the above code won't stop and tell me there's a runtime error. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Check to see if you have "On Error Resume Next" line somewhere in the code.  This code bypass errors
2) Check if there's actually a hidden worksheet called "Random"?

Comment: Thank you! I had "On Error Resume Next". Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I can help, anytime

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `On Error GoTo 0`.

It will turn error displaying back on.